How can I ensure that the model is downloaded before using it for the first time
I browsed to this URL: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/android
There is a line on the website that says:Through Google Play Services a.k.a. “thin” (recommended) - this reduces the app size and the model is shared between applications. However, developers will need to ensure that the model is downloaded before using it for the first time.
Here is my log:
2024-10-10 10:32:54.762  8519-8519  MobileVisionBase        com.metsakuur.ufacemangopublic       E  Error preloading model resource
                                                                                                    com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Waiting for the face module to be downloaded. Please wait.
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zza.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@@17.1.0:10)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zzh.load(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@@17.1.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:4)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzt.run(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:4)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd(com.google.mlkit:common@@18.5.0:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzi.run(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                    Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.vision.face found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:67)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zza.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@@17.1.0:1)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zza.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@@17.1.0:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zza.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@@17.1.0:22)
                                                                                                        at com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zza.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection@@17.1.0:5)

I know that I just need to wait for it to finish downloading the model in the background, but how can I actively download it or make sure it has been downloaded, what is the progress, is it an apk, can I build it into my device separately?

When you trigger the inference, it will auto-trigger the downloading if the module is not ready.
Also you can use the ModuleInstallClient API to trigger downloading & check whether the module is downloaded.
moduleInstallClient
    .areModulesAvailable(faceDetector)
    .addOnSuccessListener()

Also you can configure to auto-download the module after apk is installed through this link
